# Append to string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What I have is very simply this:

```
myDir = location.href;
myDir = myDir.substring(0,hipsDir.lastIndexOf("/",hipsDir.length));
```

Now myDir will point to the current folder. Now all I want is to get the variable to point to a different folder. So instead of /path/to/this/ I would like to have /path/to/this/and/that

I just can't figure out how to append the string here…

Comment: `myDir = myDir.substring(0,hipsDir.lastIndexOf("/",hipsDir.length)) + '/and/that';` ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) will append a string to a variable.

```
myDir += "and/that";
```

Or you can combine a regular assignment and a concatenation:

```
myDir = myDir + "and/that";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the *variable* to a new string with some more characters added to it, just use `+=`:

```
var str = 'abc';
str += 'def';
console.log(str); // => 'abcdef'
```

If you want to update the *string*—e.g., if other variables are referencing it—it's a no-go. Strings are immutable in JavaScript.

```
var s1 = 'abc';
var s2 = s1;
s1 += 'def';
console.log(s2); // => 'abc'
```